# How to read a particular cell by using "wb = load_workbook('path', True)" in openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

there

I have written code for reading the large excel files

but my requirement is to read a particular cell like for e.g(cell(row,column) in a excel file when i kept `True`

in `wb = load_workbook('Path', True)`

any body please help me...

## CODE:

```
 from openpyxl import load_workbook 

 wb = load_workbook('Path', True) 
 sheet_ranges = wb.get_sheet_by_name(name = 'Global') 
 for row in sheet_ranges.iter_rows(): 

     for cell in row: 
         print cell.internal_value
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using an [Optimized Reader](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/optimized.html), you cannot just access an arbitrary cell using `ws.cell(row, column).value`:

> cell, range, rows, columns methods and properties are disabled

Optimized reader was designed and created specially for reading an umlimited amount of data from an excel file by using [iterators](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types).

Basically you should iterate over rows and cells until you get the necessary cell. Here's a simple example:

```
for r, row in enumerate(sheet_ranges.iter_rows()):
    if r == 10: 
        for c, cell in enumerate(row): 
            if c == 5:
                print cell.internal_value
```

Comment: hi..alecxe , i used the same code which you specified ,but it is not entering in to first 'if ' condition and getting terminated with out printing anything

Answer (score -1):

You can find the answer [here](http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/tutorial.html#accessing-one-cell).
I recommend you consult the documentation first before asking a question on SO.

In particular, this is pretty much exactly what you want:

```
d = ws.cell(row = 4, column = 2)
```

where ws is a worksheet.

Comment: Thanks for your response ... the above code will work when "wb = load_workbook('Path', True)" there in False in True's place, when we use that it will gives the following error message " raise NotImplementedError("use 'iter_rows()' instead")
NotImplementedError: use 'iter_rows()' instead"..

Comment: Hi..DevEight, i want a particular cell value by using 'iter_rows()' can u please help me in that way

Comment: @user2823507 I suggest you read the documentation as DevEight said.

Comment: The OP asks for a different thing. He is using an optimized reader instead of a normal one.